# Jquery Ajax Call - Passing multiple parameters avoiding name dependant

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery

In my asp.net mvc 4 application I do an ajax call to a controller method that has below signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(string param1, string param2)
```

Currently my ajax call is working and I know how to pass multiple parameters, see below:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/DoSomething/",
        data: { param1: "this is param1", param2: "this is param2" },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

But the problem here is that ajax call is totally dependant on the name of the parameters of the controller method, I mean, when passing parameters in the ajax call to the controller method, those parameters must be named the same as in the controller signature so is there any way to avoid name dependant? for example, without indicating parameter name in the ajax call and put them in order so the controller method knows that first parameter passed corresponds to the first parameter, second parameter passed to the second one and so on...

Comment: there is only one body in POST method, that means there could be one parameter in method accepting POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you tried declaring the post function this way;

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(string args[]) 
/* I'm not sure which language you're using on the asp side, 
 * but the default array passed to a function is usually `args`
 */
```

and then you can use all passed parameters as they are in an array, and you can pass any amount of parameters?

Answer (score 2):

you can pass a array

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(string[] param)

$.ajax({
        url: "/DoSomething/",
        data: $.param({ param : ["this is param1","this is param2"] }),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

for more info check the docs here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? jQuery supports arrays as data.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/DoSomething/",
    data: { params:[ "this is param1", "this is param2" ]},
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
});
```